# Javascript Drag&Drop in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop

I implemented a Drag&Drop function for a website. Chrome works fine, IE9 does too (somehow), but Firefox refuses to accept my code someway.

I can click on the draggable object and Firefox fires the ondragstart event, but doesn't go any further. The draggable object does not show up and nothing is following my mouse movement. If I click another time on it, the same thing happens, so Javscript doesn't get killed.

This is my code:

```
    self.allDraggables.on({
            dragstart:self.startDragging,
            dragend:self.stopDragging
        });

self.allDroppables.on({
            dragenter:self.enterDroppable,
            dragover:self.overDroppable,
            dragleave:self.leaveDroppable,
            drop:self.dropped
        });



this.startDragging = function () {
        $('div.insidePopup span.close').trigger('click');
        self.createWidget(this);
        self.allDroppables.animate({opacity:self.options.light},    self.options.animation);
    };

    this.stopDragging = function () {
        self.destroyWidget();
        self.allDroppables.animate({opacity:self.options.unlight}, self.options.animation);
    };

this.enterDroppable = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).animate({opacity:1}, self.options.animation);
};

this.overDroppable = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};

this.leaveDroppable = function () {
    $(this).animate({opacity:self.options.light}, self.options.animation);
};
```

self refers to the main this pointer and since in Chrome and IE9 everything works okay, it can't be something in the syntax, can it?

This is really a problem, I got a presentation on monday and need to fix this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: I'm using Firefox 11.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? What version? I see $ so I'm assuming yes?

Comment: Any reason you are writing your own draggable instead of using jQuery UI?

Comment: Finally i had time to rewrite to jQuery UI and that was the best to do.